# If there is no more given inputs of numbers in a program, how will I stop it?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum, iteration

calculate the sum of digits of a given input of numbers

I can write:

```
sum = 0
while i < n:
    sum = sum + i
    i = i + 1
print(sum)
```

What would n be though or how do I clarify that the in program?

Was this just a badly written question by my instructor?

Comment: What language? Edit your question to tag a language. The variable n would need to be set by you.

Comment: Do you want the sum of each of the digits in a list of numbers or just the sum of an entered list of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your aim is to print the sum of n integers entered by the user, you can proceed to take input as:

```
values = input('Enter values as space separated numbers: ').split()
values = [int(x) for x in values]

n = len(values)
```

Then, in the code you have written, just replace `i` with `values[i]` (or whatever you have named the input variable)

```
sum = 0
i = 0
while i < n:
    sum = sum + values[i]
    i = i + 1
print(sum)
```

A sample of input could be `1 2 3 4 5`, and the program should return `15`